# Function as a template for SAPUI5 table column

Tags: jquery, sapui5

Is there a way to define a function which returns a control dynamically as a template for a column in a SAPUI5 table?

So basically one of the columns in the Model contains a comma separated value of image links which can vary in number from 1 to many. So depending on the number of links, I need to show them in same cell of the column. So here's the code I wrote :

```
    var oColumn2 = new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Fuel Type"}),
        width: "20%"
    });
    oColumn2.bindAggregation("template", "/modelData", function(sId, oContext) {
        var imgLink = oContext.getProperty("FuelType").split(",");

        var fuelLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout(sId, {
            id : "fuelMatrix",
            layoutFixed : true,
            width:"100%",   
            });

        var fuelRow = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutRow();
        fuelLayout.addRow(fuelRow);
        var fuelCell = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell();
        fuelRow.addCell(fuelCell);
        for (var n=0; n < imgLink.length; n++){
            fuelCell.addContent(new sap.ui.commons.Image({height:"30%", width:"30%", src:imgLink[n]}))
            }           
        return fuelLayout;
    });
```

The Problem is the same image repeats in every line...

Comment: Hi Abesh, what exactly are you looking for? A function which dynamically determines a control (TextView, DatePicker, RadioButton, etc) based on a certain property type?

Comment: @Qualiture I've assumed that this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [factory function in aggregation bindings](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/BindingAggregations.html), instead of a control instance.

I've put a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/vuzef/2/edit?html,js,output) together, here's the relevant section of code:

```
new sap.m.List()
  .bindItems('/people', function(sId, oContext) {
    return (oContext.getProperty('number') % 2) ?
      new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        title: '{name}',
        description: '{number}'
      }) :
      new sap.m.DisplayListItem({
        label: '{name}',
        value: '{number}'
      });
  });
```

This simple example returns a different style of list item depending on whether the value of the item's 'number' property is even or odd.